# any casualties migrating from FasterXML/Jackson from 2.8, 2.10 to 2.12 or 3.13?

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind

We are currently using JAVA8 and jackson 2.8, 2.10 version. We are planning to use the latest 2.13 or 2.12.5 . Using this will cause any problems in parsing, or annotations, or deprecated methods?

Comment: Hi Yash, the latest stable is 2.12.4, did you take a look at this page https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Releases where in the right column you can explore core changes and other changes?

Comment: Thanks, for the reply,   is there anything to keep in mind?  
for example Data formats and type changes for double in latest version. 
and dateTime stamp.